# What's the "right" way to organize GUI code?

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-guide, matlab-deployment

I'm working on a fairly sophisticated GUI program to be deployed with MATLAB Compiler. (There are good reasons MATLAB is being used to build this GUI, that is not the point of this question. I realize GUI-building is not a strong suit for this language.)

There are quite a few ways to share data between functions in a GUI, or even pass data between GUIs within an application:

- `setappdata/getappdata/_____appdata` - associate arbitrary data to a handle
- `guidata` - typically used with GUIDE; "store[s] or retrieve[s] GUI data" to a structure of handles
- Apply a `set/get` operation to the `UserData` property of a handle object
- Use nested functions within a main function; basically emulates "globally" scoping variables.
- Pass the data back and forth among subfunctions

The structure for my code is not the prettiest. Right now I have the engine segregated from the front-end (good!) but the GUI code is pretty spaghetti-like. Here's a skeleton of an "activity", to borrow Android-speak:

```
function myGui

    fig = figure(...); 

    % h is a struct that contains handles to all the ui objects to be instantiated. My convention is to have the first field be the uicontrol type I'm instantiating. See draw_gui nested function

    h = struct([]);


    draw_gui;
    set_callbacks; % Basically a bunch of set(h.(...), 'Callback', @(src, event) callback) calls would occur here

    %% DRAW FUNCTIONS

    function draw_gui
        h.Panel.Panel1 = uipanel(...
            'Parent', fig, ...
            ...);

        h.Panel.Panel2 = uipanel(...
            'Parent', fig, ...
            ...);


        draw_panel1;
        draw_panel2;

        function draw_panel1
             h.Edit.Panel1.thing1 = uicontrol('Parent', h.Panel.Panel1, ...);
        end
        function draw_panel2
             h.Edit.Panel2.thing1 = uicontrol('Parent', h.Panel.Panel2, ...);
        end


    end

    %% CALLBACK FUNCTIONS
    % Setting/getting application data is done by set/getappdata(fig, 'Foo').
end
```

I have previously-written code where nothing is nested, so I ended up passing `h` back and forth everywhere (since stuff needed to be redrawn, updated, etc) and `setappdata(fig)` to store actual data. In any case, I've been keeping one "activity" in a single file, and I'm sure this is going to be a maintenance nightmare in the future. Callbacks are interacting with both application data and graphical handle objects, which I suppose is necessary, but that's preventing a complete segregation of the two "halves" of the code base.

So I'm looking for some organizational/GUI design help here. Namely:

- Is there a directory structure I ought to be using to organize? (Callbacks vs drawing functions?)
- What's the "right way" to interact with GUI data and keep it segregated from application data? (When I refer to GUI data I mean `set/get`ting properties of handle objects).
- How do I avoid putting all these drawing functions into one giant file of thousands of lines and still efficiently pass both application and GUI data back and forth? Is that possible?
- Is there any performance penalty associated with constantly using `set/getappdata`?
- Is there any structure my back-end code (3 object classes and a bunch of helper functions) should take to make it easier to maintain from a GUI perspective?

I'm not a software engineer by trade, I just know enough to be dangerous, so I'm sure these are fairly basic questions for seasoned GUI developers (in any language). I almost feel like the lack of a GUI design standard in MATLAB (does one exist?) is seriously interfering with my ability to complete this project. This is a MATLAB project that is much more massive than any I've ever undertaken, and I've never had to give much thought to complicated UIs with multiple figure windows, etc., before.

Comment: some related question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/335535, http://stackoverflow.com/q/3490481. Also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7699788, http://stackoverflow.com/q/1115703, http://stackoverflow.com/q/16170475, http://stackoverflow.com/q/7708308

Comment: @Amro as this is a very useful question, as well as your answer, you may include this link suggestions in your answer rather than here in the comments. It's a nice start for further reading and a little lost in the comments ;)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

As [@SamRoberts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20078237/97160) explained, the [Model–view–controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) (MVC) pattern is well-suited as an architecture to design GUIs. I agree that there are not a lot of MATLAB examples out there to show such design...

Below is a complete yet simple example I wrote to demonstrate an MVC-based GUI in MATLAB.

- The **model** represents a 1D function of some signal `y(t) = sin(..t..)`. It is a handle-class object, that way we can pass the data around without creating unnecessary copies. It exposes observable properties, which allows other components to listen for change notifications.
- The **view** presents the model as a line graphics object. The view also contains a slider to control one of the signal properties, and listens to model change notifications. I also included an interactive property which is specific to the view (not the model), where the line color can be controlled using the right-click context menu.
- The **controller** is responsible of initializing everything and responding to events from the view and correctly updating the model accordingly.

Note that the view and controller are written as regular functions, but you could write classes if you prefer fully object-oriented code.

It is a little extra work compared to the usual way of designing GUIs, but one of the advantages of such architecture is the separation of the data from presentation layer. This makes for a cleaner and more readable code especially when working with complex GUIs, where code maintenance becomes more difficult.

This design is very flexible as it allows you to build multiple views of the same data. Even more you can have multiple *simultaneous* views, just instantiate more views instances in the controller and see how changes in one view are propagated to the other! This is especially interesting if your model can be visually presented in different ways.

In addition, if you prefer you can use the GUIDE editor to build interfaces instead of programmatically adding controls. In such a design we would only use GUIDE to build the GUI components using drag-and-drop, but we would not write any callback functions. So we'll only be interested in the `.fig` file produced, and just ignore the accompanying `.m` file. We would setup the callbacks in the view function/class. This is basically what I did in the `View_FrequencyDomain` view component, which loads the existing FIG-file built using GUIDE.

[image: GUIDE generated FIG-file]

---

#### Model.m

```
classdef Model < handle
    %MODEL  represents a signal composed of two components + white noise
    % with sampling frequency FS defined over t=[0,1] as:
    %   y(t) = a * sin(2pi * f*t) + sin(2pi * 2*f*t) + white_noise

    % observable properties, listeners are notified on change
    properties (SetObservable = true)
        f       % frequency components in Hz
        a       % amplitude
    end

    % read-only properties
    properties (SetAccess = private)
        fs      % sampling frequency (Hz)
        t       % time vector (seconds)
        noise   % noise component
    end

    % computable dependent property
    properties (Dependent = true, SetAccess = private)
        data    % signal values
    end

    methods
        function obj = Model(fs, f, a)
            % constructor
            if nargin < 3, a = 1.2; end
            if nargin < 2, f = 5; end
            if nargin < 1, fs = 100; end
            obj.fs = fs;
            obj.f = f;
            obj.a = a;

            % 1 time unit with 'fs' samples
            obj.t = 0 : 1/obj.fs : 1-(1/obj.fs);
            obj.noise = 0.2 * obj.a * rand(size(obj.t));
        end

        function y = get.data(obj)
            % signal data
            y = obj.a * sin(2*pi * obj.f*obj.t) + ...
                sin(2*pi * 2*obj.f*obj.t) + obj.noise;
        end
    end

    % business logic
    methods
        function [mx,freq] = computePowerSpectrum(obj)
            num = numel(obj.t);
            nfft = 2^(nextpow2(num));

            % frequencies vector (symmetric one-sided)
            numUniquePts = ceil((nfft+1)/2);
            freq = (0:numUniquePts-1)*obj.fs/nfft;

            % compute FFT
            fftx = fft(obj.data, nfft);

            % calculate magnitude
            mx = abs(fftx(1:numUniquePts)).^2 / num;
            if rem(nfft, 2)
                mx(2:end) = mx(2:end)*2;
            else
                mx(2:end -1) = mx(2:end -1)*2;
            end
        end
    end
end
```

#### View_TimeDomain.m

```
function handles = View_TimeDomain(m)
    %VIEW  a GUI representation of the signal model

    % build the GUI
    handles = initGUI();
    onChangedF(handles, m);    % populate with initial values

    % observe on model changes and update view accordingly
    % (tie listener to model object lifecycle)
    addlistener(m, 'f', 'PostSet', ...
        @(o,e) onChangedF(handles,e.AffectedObject));
end

function handles = initGUI()
    % initialize GUI controls
    hFig = figure('Menubar','none');
    hAx = axes('Parent',hFig, 'XLim',[0 1], 'YLim',[-2.5 2.5]);
    hSlid = uicontrol('Parent',hFig, 'Style','slider', ...
        'Min',1, 'Max',10, 'Value',5, 'Position',[20 20 200 20]);
    hLine = line('XData',NaN, 'YData',NaN, 'Parent',hAx, ...
        'Color','r', 'LineWidth',2);

    % define a color property specific to the view
    hMenu = uicontextmenu;
    hMenuItem = zeros(3,1);
    hMenuItem(1) = uimenu(hMenu, 'Label','r', 'Checked','on');
    hMenuItem(2) = uimenu(hMenu, 'Label','g');
    hMenuItem(3) = uimenu(hMenu, 'Label','b');
    set(hLine, 'uicontextmenu',hMenu);

    % customize
    xlabel(hAx, 'Time (sec)')
    ylabel(hAx, 'Amplitude')
    title(hAx, 'Signal in time-domain')

    % return a structure of GUI handles
    handles = struct('fig',hFig, 'ax',hAx, 'line',hLine, ...
        'slider',hSlid, 'menu',hMenuItem);
end

function onChangedF(handles,model)
    % respond to model changes by updating view
    if ~ishghandle(handles.fig), return, end
    set(handles.line, 'XData',model.t, 'YData',model.data)
    set(handles.slider, 'Value',model.f);
end
```

#### View_FrequencyDomain.m

```
function handles = View_FrequencyDomain(m)    
    handles = initGUI();
    onChangedF(handles, m);

    hl = event.proplistener(m, findprop(m,'f'), 'PostSet', ...
        @(o,e) onChangedF(handles,e.AffectedObject));
    setappdata(handles.fig, 'proplistener',hl);
end

function handles = initGUI()
    % load FIG file (its really a MAT-file)
    hFig = hgload('ViewGUIDE.fig');
    %S = load('ViewGUIDE.fig', '-mat');

    % extract handles to GUI components
    hAx = findobj(hFig, 'tag','axes1');
    hSlid = findobj(hFig, 'tag','slider1');
    hTxt = findobj(hFig, 'tag','fLabel');
    hMenu = findobj(hFig, 'tag','cmenu1');
    hMenuItem = findobj(hFig, 'type','uimenu');

    % initialize line and hook up context menu
    hLine = line('XData',NaN, 'YData',NaN, 'Parent',hAx, ...
        'Color','r', 'LineWidth',2);
    set(hLine, 'uicontextmenu',hMenu);

    % customize
    xlabel(hAx, 'Frequency (Hz)')
    ylabel(hAx, 'Power')
    title(hAx, 'Power spectrum in frequency-domain')

    % return a structure of GUI handles
    handles = struct('fig',hFig, 'ax',hAx, 'line',hLine, ...
        'slider',hSlid, 'menu',hMenuItem, 'txt',hTxt);
end

function onChangedF(handles,model)
    [mx,freq] = model.computePowerSpectrum();
    set(handles.line, 'XData',freq, 'YData',mx)
    set(handles.slider, 'Value',model.f)
    set(handles.txt, 'String',sprintf('%.1f Hz',model.f))
end
```

#### Controller.m

```
function [m,v1,v2] = Controller
    %CONTROLLER  main program

    % controller knows about model and view
    m = Model(100);           % model is independent
    v1 = View_TimeDomain(m);  % view has a reference of model

    % we can have multiple simultaneous views of the same data
    v2 = View_FrequencyDomain(m);

    % hook up and respond to views events
    set(v1.slider, 'Callback',{@onSlide,m})
    set(v2.slider, 'Callback',{@onSlide,m})
    set(v1.menu, 'Callback',{@onChangeColor,v1})
    set(v2.menu, 'Callback',{@onChangeColor,v2})

    % simulate some change
    pause(3)
    m.f = 10;
end

function onSlide(o,~,model)
    % update model (which in turn trigger event that updates view)
    model.f = get(o,'Value');
end

function onChangeColor(o,~,handles)
    % update view
    clr = get(o,'Label');
    set(handles.line, 'Color',clr)
    set(handles.menu, 'Checked','off')
    set(o, 'Checked','on')
end
```

[image: MVC GUI1]
[image: MVC GUI2]

In the controller above, I instantiate two separate but synchronized views, both representing and responding to changes in the same underlying model. One view shows the time-domain of the signal, and another shows the frequency-domain representation using FFT.

Comment: Thanks for connecting the dots with the GUIDE-generate .fig via `hgload`, as GUIDE is a useful tool even if you decide not to use the callbacks which it generates.

Comment: To extend this - I probably need a different model/controller/view for every GUI I build for my application? Maybe I can keep a single model and have multiple controllers/views. How does this scale to an application with lots and lots of windows?

Comment: @DangKhoa: both the view and controller are loosely coupled to the model's interface, therefore we usually have one model, and as many view/controller pairs as you want. I have updated my example to show two different views of the same data, while being synchronized. You could probably refactor things a bit to reduce this coupling and make reusable controllers across views, but you will still have to follow the guidelines of how the MVC components interact (model being independent, view dependent on model, and controller dependent on both): http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/148377/1379

Comment: @Amro, although it shows a lot of helpfulness on your part to provide such an extensive example (so +1), there's a couple of areas in which I think your answer doesn't demonstrate best practice or advice. In particular, I'd advise i) don't use GUIDE - for many reasons, but particularly because .fig files aren't version controllable (well, diffable anyway) so an application developed in this way will be harder to maintain ii) ...

Comment: @ Amro ... ii) this is maybe more my opinion/preference than a fact, but GUIs with multiple windows are much more of a pain to organise, and unless there are very strong reasons otherwise, are just bad usability. Particularly if you're using GUI Layout Toolbox, for most applications there are single window designs that are easier to maintain and are more usable.

Comment: @SamRoberts: thanks. i) you are right, I myself dont recommend using GUIDE in this manner. I showed two view implementations, one of them using GUIDE just to demonstrate that it is possible. ii) I am also in agreement here, but keep in mind that views dont necessarily have to create top-level figures; we could design a view such that it draws inside a `uipanel` container instead, that way multiple views can be combined into one figure. The GUI Layout Toolbox, which is an excellent package, could be used here as well in combination with the MVC pattern

Comment: @Amro - kind of off topic so we can take this to chat - but do you have any recommendations for folder organization within a large-scale MATLAB project that would use MVC? Again, I'm not a software engineer, and I'd like to keep my code as clean and maintainable as possible. We're getting into [architect astronaut](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2004/12/it-came-from-planet-architecture.html) territory here, but humor me.

Comment: @DangKhoa: I would organize the code the same way I do any project and follow good coding [principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29); personally I try to avoid as much as possible polluting the global namespace by using packages and private functions. In addition it's good practice to separate the logical tiers in a MVC application (data, business logic, presentation). If your application is data-oriented and talks to a database backend, you might want to use [ORM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) to abstract the data access layer.

Comment: .. there are lots of materials online on the subject of MVC best practices, although I'm not sure how much of it is applicable in the MATLAB world! (search for: separation of concerns, n-tier architectures, MVC persistence patterns, inversion of control, etc...). You could also start thinking about unit-testing the various components of the MVC, mock testing, and so on. Eventually I think it's up to you to choose how much you are willing to integrate in your application, after all it is a lot of work :)

Comment: If your application grows beyond what you can easily accomplish in MATLAB, then it might be a good time to start thinking about using another tool best-suited for the task at hand. For instance you could design the GUI in Java (with all the frameworks and libraries it has to offer), and drive the program from inside MATLAB (MVC design encourages a separated presentation layer which can be swapped by another view). After all, the MATLAB IDE itself and many of its graphical tools are written in Java :)

Comment: @Amro I keep on coming back to this answer as a great reference, and 1 year later I've learned a lot about GUIs and MVC :) In your controller example, your callbacks directly access the `handles` struct. If you instead used classes instead of functions, wouldn't this be a violation of the [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter)? It's easier to access the `handles` struct directly, but it would probably be better (and add mroe work) to make `handles` private and expose methods to manipulate the `uicontrol`s?

Answer (score 10):

The [`UserData` property](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/ways-to-manage-data-in-a-programmatic-gui.html#f13-999769) is a useful, but legacy, property of MATLAB objects. The "AppData" suite of methods (i.e. `setappdata`, `getappdata`, `rmappdata`, `isappdata`, etc.) provide a great alternative to the comparatively more clumsy `get/set(hFig,'UserData',dataStruct)` approach, IMO. In fact, to manage GUI data, GUIDE employs **the [`guidata`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/guidata.html) function, which is just a wrapper for the `setappdata`/`getappdata` functions**.

A couple of advantages of the AppData approach over the `'UserData'` property that come to mind:

- More natural interface for multiple heterogeneous properties.

  **`UserData` is limited to a single variable**, requiring you to devise another layer of data oranization (i.e. a struct). Say you want to store a string `str = 'foo'` and a numeric array `v=[1 2]`. With `UserData`, you would need to adopt a struct scheme such as `s = struct('str','foo','v',[1 2]);` and `set/get` the whole thing whenever you want either property (e.g. `s.str = 'bar'; set(h,'UserData',s);`). With `setappdata`, the process is more direct (and efficient): `setappdata(h,'str','bar');`.
- Protected interface to the underlying storage space.

  While `'UserData'` is just a regular handle graphics property, the property containing the application data is not visible, although it can be accessed by name ('ApplicationData', but don't do it!).  You have to use `setappdata` to change any existing AppData properties, which prevents you from accidentally clobbering the entire contents of `'UserData'` while trying to update a single field. Also, before setting or getting an AppData property, you can verify the existence of a named property with `isappdata`, which can help with exception handling (e.g. run a process callback before setting input values) and managing the state of the GUI or the tasks which it governs (e.g. infer state of a process by existence of certain properties and update GUI appropriately).

An important difference between the `'UserData'` and `'ApplicationData'` properties is that `'UserData'` is by default `[]` (an empty array), while `'ApplicationData'` is natively a struct. This difference, together with the fact that `setappdata` and `getappdata` have no M-file implementation (they are built-in), suggests that **setting a named property with `setappdata` does *not* require rewriting the entire contents of the data struct**. (Imagine a MEX function that performs a in-place modification of a struct field - an operation MATLAB is able to implement by maintaining a struct as the underlying data representation of the `'ApplicationData'` handle graphics property.)

---

**The `guidata` function is a wrapper to the AppData functions, but it is limited to a single variable, like `'UserData'`**. That means you have to overwrite the entire data structure containing all of your data fields to update a single field. A stated advantage is that you can access the data from a callback without needing the actual figure handle, but as far as I am concerned, this is not a big advantage if you are comfortable with the following statement:

```
hFig = ancestor(hObj,'Figure')
```

Also, [as stated by MathWorks](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/102591), there are efficiency issues:

> Saving large amounts of data in the 'handles' structure can sometimes cause a considerable slowdown, especially if GUIDATA is often called within the various sub-functions of the GUI. For this reason, it is recommended to use the 'handles' structure only to store handles to graphics objects. For other kinds of data, SETAPPDATA and GETAPPDATA should be used to store it as application data.

This statement supports my assertion that the entire `'ApplicationData'` is not rewritten when using `setappdata` to modify a single named property. (On the other hand, `guidata` crams the `handles` structure into a field of `'ApplicationData'` called `'UsedByGUIData_m'`, so it is clear why `guidata` would need to rewrite all of the GUI data when one property is changed).

---

Nested functions require very little effort (no auxiliary structures or functions needed), but they obviously limit the scope of data to the GUI, making it impossible for other GUIs or functions to access that data without returning values to the base workspace or a common calling function.  Obviously this prevents you from splitting sub-functions out into separate files, something that you can easily do with `'UserData'` or AppData as long as you pass the figure handle.

---

In summary, if you choose to use handle properties to store and pass data, it is possible to use both `guidata` to manage graphics handles (not large data) *and* `setappdata`/`getappdata` for actual program data. **They will not overwrite each other** since `guidata` makes a special `'UsedByGUIData_m'` field in `ApplicationData` for the `handles` structure (unless you make the mistake of using that property yourself!). Just to reiterate, do not directly access `ApplicationData`.

**However, if you are comfortable with OOP, it may be cleaner to implement GUI functionality via a class**, with handles and other data stored in member variables rather than handle properties, and callbacks in methods that can exist in [separate files under the class or package folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9781866/folder-and-folder). There is a [nice example on MATLAB Central File Exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/33816-example-using-a-matlab-class-to-control-a-gui). This submission demonstrates how passing data is simplified with a class since it is no longer necessary to constantly get and update `guidata` (members variables are always up to date). However there is the additional task of managing cleanup on exit, which the submission accomplishes by setting the figure's `closerequestfcn`, which then calls the `delete` function of the class. The submission nicely parallels the GUIDE example.

Those are the highlights as I see them, but many more details and different ideas are [discussed by MathWorks](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/ways-to-manage-data-in-a-programmatic-gui.html). See also [this official answer](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/102591) to `UserData` vs. `guidata` vs. `setappdata/getappdata`.

Comment: In the end, getappdata/setappdata is nothing more than wrapper for getting/setting in structure that's stored in the hidden figure property `ApplicationData` rather than in `UserData`. So, performance wise they should be pretty similar.

Comment: @sebastian I wouldn't necessarily reach that conclusion. For one thing, MathWorks statement that `getappdata`/`setappdata` has better performance than `guidata` implies that not all of the struct in `ApplicationData` needs to be rewritten.  Also, if you do `get(h,'ApplicationData')` you see that it _is natively a structure_, whereas `get(h,'UserData')` is `[]`, requiring you to _store a structure in the property_. The fact that there are no M-file implementations of `getappdata`/`setappdata` suggests a more efficient access method to the `ApplicationData` struct property.

Comment: So you'd also store GUI data (e.g., "handles struct") as `ApplicationData` as well? I suppose it doesn't really make much of a difference. Just want to define a convention and stick with it

Comment: @DangKhoa You could use `guidata` to store graphics handles (not user data) AND `set/getappdata` for the actual data.  They will not overwrite each other since `guidata` uses the special `'UsedByGUIData_m'` property of `ApplicationData` (unless you make the mistake of using that property yourself!). From [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/ways-to-manage-data-in-a-programmatic-gui.html#f13-998905): "Using the getappdata, setappdata, and rmappdata functions does not affect GUI data." And just to reiterate, do not directly access `'ApplicationData'`.

Answer (score 7):

I disagree that MATLAB is not good for implementing (even complex) GUIs - it's perfectly fine.

However, what is true is that:

1. There are no examples in the MATLAB documentation of how to implement or organize a complex GUI application
2. All the documentation examples of simple GUIs use patterns that do not scale well at all to complex GUIs
3. In particular, GUIDE (the built-in tool for auto-generating GUI code) generates terrible code that is a dreadful example to follow if you're implementing something yourself.

Because of these things, most people are only exposed to either very simple or really horrible MATLAB GUIs, and they end up thinking MATLAB is not suitable for making GUIs.

In my experience the best way to implement a complex GUI in MATLAB is the same way as you would in another language - follow a well-used pattern such as MVC (model-view-controller).

However, this is an object-oriented pattern, so first you'll have to get comfortable with object-oriented programming in MATLAB, and particularly with the use of events. Using an object-oriented organization for your application should mean that all the nasty techniques you mention (`setappdata`, `guidata`, `UserData`, nested function scoping, and passing back and forth multiple data copies) are not necessary, as all the relevant things are available as class properties.

The best example I know of that MathWorks has published is in [this article](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/company/newsletters/articles/writing-apps-in-matlab.html) from MATLAB Digest. Even that example is very simple, but it gives you an idea of how to start off, and if you look into the MVC pattern it should become clear how to extend it.

In addition, I typically make heavy use of package folders to organize large codebases in MATLAB, to ensure there are no name clashes.

One final tip - use the [GUI Layout Toolbox](https://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27758-gui-layout-toolbox), from MATLAB Central. It makes many aspects of GUI development much easier, particularly implementing automatic resize behaviour, and gives you several additional UI elements to use.

Hope that helps!

---

Edit: In MATLAB R2016a MathWorks introduced AppDesigner, a new GUI-building framework intended to gradually replace GUIDE.

AppDesigner represents a major break with previous GUI-building approaches in MATLAB in several ways (most deeply, the underlying figure windows generated are based on an HTML canvas and JavaScript, rather than Java). It is another step along a road initiated by the introduction of Handle Graphics 2 in R2014b, and will doubtless evolve further over future releases.

But one impact of AppDesigner on the question asked is that it generates **much** better code than GUIDE did - it's pretty clean, object-oriented, and suitable to form the basis of an MVC pattern.

Comment: This is very helpful! I'm comfortable with MATLAB OOP and events, and I'm also using the GUI Layout Toolbox (mostly for the `TabPanel`). I'll read into the MVC design pattern.

Comment: +1 MVC is a well known design to to separate the data layer from the presentation layer. I posted an example with one possible MVC implementation.

Answer (score 2):

I am very uncomfortable with the way GUIDE produces functions. (think about cases where you'd like to call one gui from another)

I would strongly suggest you write your code object oriented using handle classes. That way you can do fancy stuffs (e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153044/is-it-possible-to-do-stateless-programming-in-matlab-how-to-avoid-checking-d/9153153#9153153)) and not get lost. For organizing code you have the `+` and `@` directories.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think structuring GUI-code is fundamentally different from non-GUI code.

Put things that belong together, together at some location.
Like helper-functions that might go into a `util` or `helpers` directory. Depending on the content, maybe make it a package.

---

Personally I don't like the "one function one m-file" philosophy some MATLAB people have.
Putting a function like:

```
function pushbutton17_callback(hObject,evt, handles)
    some_text = someOtherFunction();
    set(handles.text45, 'String', some_text);
end
```

into a seperate file simply makes no sense, when there's no scenario whatsoever you'd call this from somewhere else then from your own GUI.

---

You can however build the GUI itself in a modular way, by e.g. creating certain components by simply passing the parent container:

```
 handles.panel17 = uipanel(...);
 createTable(handles.panel17); % creates a table in the specified panel
```

This also simplifies testing of certain sub-components - you could simply call `createTable` on an empty figure and test certain functionalities of the table without loading the full application.

---

Just two additional items I started using when my application became increasingly larger:

Use listeners over callbacks, they can simplify GUI programming significantly.

If you have really large data (such as from a database, etc.) it might be worthwhile implementing a handle-class holding this data.
Storing this handle somewhere in the guidata/appdata significantly improves get/setappdata performance.

**Edit:**

Listeners over callbacks:

A `pushbutton` is bad example. Pushing a button usually only triggers on certain action, here callbacks are fine imho.
A main advantage in my case e.g. was that programmatically changing text/popup lists does not trigger callbacks, while listeners on their `String` or `Value` property are triggered.

Another example:

If there's some central property (e.g. like some source of inputdata) that multiple components in the application depend on, then using listeners is very convenient to assure that all components are notified if the property changes.
Every new component "interested" in this property can simply add it's own listener, so there's no need to centrally modify the callback.
This allows for a much more modular design of the GUI components and makes adding/removing of such components easier.

Comment: Can you give an example for using listeners over callbacks? How can you get around using callbacks for, say, a `pushbutton` object being pressed?

Comment: I've added an example to my answer.