# how to send parameters from one call back to other callback?

Tags: matlab, callback, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I have these callback functions:

```
function q7_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)

-----
-----
function column_icrement_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

----
----

function row_icrement_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
----
----

function width_increment_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
---
---
```

These are the last 3 functions that I want to send parameters to from `function q7_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)`. I have successfully loaded the picture but I am not sure whether I can send more than 3 parameters or not for adjusting row,col, height, width?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do NOT use global variables.  Use the `handles` structure to pass this data.

In `q7_OpeningFcn`, store this data (e.g. `handles.rows=...`).

In the callbacks, you will have the data in the `handles` struct.

If you change values in `handles` in your callbacks, you need to run `guidata(hObject,handles)`. See [Store Data Using the `guidata` Function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/share-data-among-callbacks.html#bt9p4xi) and the example there.

You can also use [`setappdata`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/setappdata.html)/[`getappdata`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/getappdata.html) to store and retrieve data *by name* (["application data"](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/share-data-among-callbacks.html#bt9p4t0)).  See the article [Share Data Among Callbacks](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/share-data-among-callbacks.html) for details on both approaches.

[Even more on storing data in a GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20065967/2778484).

Comment: could you illustrate how shell i use? i like your approach as it looks like dynamic can you. i am unable to produce while writing code??

Comment: If you create a GUI with GUIDE, it will be used throughout, with comments on it's usage.  Also see [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/guidata.html) for examples.  See my edits. [Here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/share-data-among-callbacks.html#bt9p4xi) is a minimal example.

Comment: thnx a lot very informative. help me when i need your help. thnxx

Answer (score 0):

define global variables.
http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/global.html

in summary: put `global row, col, ...` at the beginning of `q7_OpeningFcn`.  then in each function that is in charge of one of those variables put `global row=value` in that function.

for example:

```
function q7_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    global column, row, width
    doStuff 
end

function column_icrement_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    global column
    column=value
end

function row_icrement_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    global row
    row=value
end

function width_increment_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    global width
    width=value
end
```

Comment: apart from this question. is it possible to place check if button is prssed then increment the value?