# How to update a uitable after creation from other functions?

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-figure, matlab-guide, matlab-uitable

I created a matfile in which I store data that are constantly overwritten by user behavior. This occurs in a function "test()".

```
n=1
while n < 5 
    myVal = double(Test704(1, 780, -1)) %Returns the user's behavior
    if myVal == 1
        n = n + 1 %"n" is the overwritten variable in the matfile
    end

    save('testSave1.mat') %The matfile
    m = matfile('testSave1.mat')
end
```

Then, I want to display these data in another function (it is essential to have two separated functions) called "storageTest()". More particularly, storageTest() is a GUI function where I developped an uitable "t". So, I first call the function "test()" and give its output values as data of "t". Here is the code of the interesting part of "storageTest":

```
m = test()
    d = [m.n]
    t = uitable('Data',d, ...
        'ColumnWidth',{50}, ...
        'Position',[100 100 461 146]);
    t.Position(3) = t.Extent(3);
    t.Position(4) = t.Extent(4);

    drawnow
```

This code executes only when "m = test()" running is over and displays me a tab in which I can see the final value of "n". However, I want my table to be displayed before and to see my value incrementing according to user's behavior.
I have searched on the web to solve my issue, but I cannot find any answer, is it possible to do such a thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming I'm interpreting the question correctly, it should be fairly trivial to accomplish this if you initialize your table prior to calling `test` and then pass the handle to your table for `test` to update in the `while` loop:

For example:

```
function testGUI
% Initialize table
t = uitable('ColumnWidth',{50}, 'Position',[100 100 461 146]);
test(t)

function test(t)
n = 1;
while n < 5
    n = n + 1;
    t.Data = n;
    pause(0.25); % Since we're just incrementing a number, a slight so we can actually see the change
end
```

When you run the above, you'll notice the data in your table iterating as expected.

Comment: Many thanks @excaza! However, do you think I can still store the data ? My aim, by using a matfile was to keep a record of variable "n" values (I want to do so because I want to know at which time the user did this action, so it is important for me).

Comment: @ManaV yes, your code doesn't need to change from what you've provided above, just the addition of the `t.data = whatever` to `test` and initializing `t` prior to calling `test` and passing `t` to `test` (or utilizing [thewaywewalk's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32145207/how-to-update-a-uitable-after-creation-from-other-functions/32145884#32145884), which functions similarly).

Answer (score 2):

[**excaza**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32145833/2605073) was a little faster in writing basically the same answer like me. As it looks a slightly different, I'll post it anyway.

```
function storagetest()
    close all
    f = figure;
    data = [1];
    t = uitable(f,'Data',data,'ColumnWidth',{50});
    test()
end

function test()
    % handle uitable
    t = evalin('caller','t')

    n = 1;
    while n < 5
        newVal = input('Enter a number:');
        data = get(t,'Data');
        set(t,'Data', [data; newVal]);
        n = n + 1;
    end

end
```

The "user behaviour" I imitated with the `input` function. The basic idea is to update your table from within `test()`. `evalin` you can use, if you don't want to pass parameters to `test()`, though passing the handle of the uitable directly is certainly the better option.

If you are working on a serious GUI project I highly recommend you reading [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20064610/whats-the-right-way-to-organize-gui-code).

Comment: Great link, hadn't seen that question before!

Comment: Thank you @thewaywewalk, I wish I could select your answer as the correct one too!

Comment: Dont worry excaza was faster and the answers are basically the same